# MySQL PREG_CAPTURE regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I have the following example:

```
SELECT
    PREG_CAPTURE('/(#[^ ]*)/i', sentence, 1, 1) AS result_1,
    PREG_CAPTURE('/(#[^ ]*)/i', sentence, 1, 2) AS result_2

FROM (
    SELECT 'Hello #world #everyone' AS sentence
) tmp
```

Returning:

```
result_1 | result_2
---------|-----------
#world   | #everyone
```

As you can see, **PREG_CAPTURE** is:

```
PREG_CAPTURE(pattern, subject [, capture-group] [, occurence])
```

All I need is to return all ocurrences until the result is **NULL** on the same column. So, instead of having several *result_x* columns, I would have only one column *result*. Also, I need to group these results and count them on a separate column.

So the result would look like:

```
result    | count
----------|-------
#world    | 1
#everyone | 1
```

How can I accomplish that?

I'm using the following library for **regex** usage on mysql: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg

Answer (score 1):

MySQL follows a basic convention, which is: SELECT's can only select a part of a given subset, it can never create more lines that what has been given to him. So if you return 10 lines on your clause, SELECT statements cannot produce 15 lines of output.

Another option I've thought was using basic regexs on your WHERE clause and then splitting single line results into multiple columns, but that is basically what PREG_CAPTURE (a user defined function) has already provided to you.

Sorry I couldn't help any further.